# "qemu-img": overwriting a running OS?

Tags: qemu, sles

Is it possible that I would issue a:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O raw sles12_3_custom.qcow2 /dev/sda
```

while the original SLES11 is running?

So I would overwrite a SLES11 OS, while it is running (only having sda in the machine) with a SLES12.3 qcow2 image.

Or the SLES11 would crash at half way?

When the qemu-img command would finish, I would issue a power off (not reboot)

Would it increase the chances of a successful overwrite if I stop all the services on the SLES11? Ex.: app or logging, etc.? And put the qcow2 image in /dev/shm/?

Comment: What is your use-case for doing this?

Comment: rebuilding to S12 as fast as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I tried it, `qcow2` image in `/dev/shm`. Didn't crashed.

After qemu-img finished, I reseted the machine.

No errors in logs! :)

Comment: Whether or not it worked for you, this just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: yepp, a horrible solution! but it worked (for only a few times needed, not on many nodes)